# how to use find_in_set of mySQL in SYBASE?

Tags: mysql, sybase

Before,  I use `find_in_set(idField,:ids)` in `mySQL` to delete or update multi field with ids separated by comma, example:

```
UPDATE USER SET name = 'a' WHERE find_in_set(id,'1,2,3,4') > 0
```

How do I can customize the query and use it in SyBase ?

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: You haven't mentioned which Sybase database product you're using (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?), nor the version.  While ASE does not have anything like find_in_set(), I can't speak for the other database products.

From an ASE perspective you have a few options:

- create your own user-defined function; you have T-SQL (since ASE 15.0.2) and Java options
- build a dynamic query and submit via execute()
- rewrite your query to use available ASE functions (eg, patindex(), charindex())
- rewrite your query to use the **like** operator (see [alternate to find_in_set() for non-MySQL databases](http://blogs.digitss.com/database/alternate-to-find_in_set-for-non-mysql-databases/) for an example)

Comment: Sorry I use ASE and i use IN to fix it. BTW in java 8 i must use 
`StringJoiner userids = new StringJoiner("','","'","'");
userids.add("id1");
userids.add("id2");`
to call in query

Comment: ah, yes, if you're hard coding the list then simply rewriting the query to use `in` would (obviously) be much easier eh :-)

Answer (score 0):

As Sybase does not have function like find_in_set, you have couple of options: google a function which parses the comma separated list to a temp table or use dynamic SQL with execute-command.

Comment: I know sybase dont have find_in_set . i try to call same function that in sybase